# Can you react to an opportunity attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, opportunity-attack, reactions

Say you move out of an enemy's range, and they opportunity attack you. Can you then cast Shield as a reaction, or do another reaction when that happens?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The rules for [reactions](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#Reactions) are fairly straightforward:

> Certain special abilities, spells, and situations allow you to take a special action called a reaction. A reaction is an instant response to a trigger of some kind, which can occur **on your turn** or on someone else's. The opportunity attack, described later in this section, is the most common type of reaction.
>
> When you take a reaction, you can't take another one until the start of your next turn. If the reaction interrupts another creature's turn, that creature can continue its turn right after the reaction.

It specifically mentions being able to use reactions on your turn, so then we look to the [*shield*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/shield) spell, to see when the reaction is allowed:

> Casting Time: 1 reaction, which you take **when you are hit by an attack** or targeted by the *magic missile* spell

So yes, you would be able to use this when you are hit by an opportunity attack, as that is an attack. You would then be unable to use any more reactions until the start of your next turn.

Comment: I've fixed the capitalization in your first quote, since it seems to have been copied from Roll20 [which is known to have capitalization issues](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8218/how-to-handle-incorrect-quotations-from-3rd-party-sources) due to how the Roll20 Compendium formats links.

Comment: Thanks. Couldn't find a better formatted quote.

Comment: The bolded 'on your turn' is confusing. I would suggest bolding 'or someone else's' as well.

Comment: "On your turn" is bolded because that's when an opportunity attack would occur against you. It's why the OP was confused on if they can react or not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, provided you haven't already used your reaction that round.

Comment: I'm downvoting because although brevity is acceptable and this may be correct, fuller explanations are much more useful. Could you provide a bit of backup for this answer; maybe quote the relevant rules?

Comment: @PurpleMonkey Respectfully, while the comment is helpful, I think refraining from voting would be more appropriate than downvoting, especially in the case of a low-rep user; downvotes indicate wrong or non-useful answers, and this one is neither. Posting a correct and useful answer and getting downvoted sends a bad signal to the poster who is new to the site and to answering here.

Comment: @TylerH that may be true but there is also something to be said about it's unhelpfulness. I could say the exact opposite to this answer but without providing any evidence/backup it's not a useful answer. Answers are expected to be self contained and provide the necessary information, not provide one sentence and expect readers to confirm it's true themselves by having to read through the rules.

Comment: @PurpleMonkey The difference is you'd be wrong and know you are wrong; if you know enough to know something is correct, it seems disingenuous to downvote a correct answer simply because it's lacking citations. It's more helpful to newer users to leave the voting be and simply ask for citations.

Comment: This is incorrect, reactions do not refresh at the start of the round, but at the start of each creature's turn. So a creature *can* use two reactions per *round*, but cannot use two reactions in-between their turns.